# A question about properties of Newton's Divided Difference

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Recall that Newton's Divided Difference:
$$f[x_0,x_1]=\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0},$$
and
$$f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]=\frac{f[x_1,\ldots,x_n]-f[x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}]}{x_n-x_0},$$
where $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are distinct.

Now I have a question about properties of Newton's Divided Difference. Let $f(x)$ be a function and $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are distinct. Define 
$$g(x)=f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x].$$
How can I show that $g'(x)=f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x,x]$?

Comment: Since $h'(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{h(x+\varepsilon)-h(x)}{(x+\varepsilon)-x} = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} h[x,x+\varepsilon]$ it is enough to apply induction on $n$.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio, Thanks for your answer, however I can't understand why $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}h[x,x+\epsilon]=h[x,x]$?

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio, We know that if $h$ is a differentiable function, then
 $h[x,x+\epsilon]=h'(\xi_x)$, where $\xi_x\in(x,x+\epsilon)$. So, when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, then $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}h[x,x+\epsilon]=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}h'(\xi_x)=h'(x)$. Is that correct?

Comment: If $h$ has a continuous derivative, yes, that is correct. On the other hand, how it is possible to define $h[x,x]$ without a limit? According to the original definition, it should be $\frac{h(x)-h(x)}{x-x}$, but that is just $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, Yes, that is right. Can you explain why $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}h[x,x+\epsilon]=h[x,x]$?

Comment: I simply took that as a reasonable definition of $h[x,x]$, $$ h[x,x]\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}h[x,x+\varepsilon].$$ Otherwise, how would you define $h[x,x]$?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, Yes, based on this definition, we can get this result.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, I have prepared a answer. Since the characters have been used are  greater than the limit, I have to write as a answer. Please tell me your comments. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If we define
    $$f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x,x]\overset{\text{def}}{=}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x,x+\epsilon],$$
    then
    \begin{align*}
 g'(x)&=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+\epsilon)-g(x)}{\epsilon}\\
 &=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x+\epsilon]-f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x]}{\epsilon}\\
 &=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x+\epsilon]-f[x,x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]}{\epsilon}\\
 &=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}f[x,x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x+\epsilon]\\
 &=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,,x,x+\epsilon]\\
 &=f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,,x_n,x,x]\qquad(\text{by definition}).
 \end{align*}
Therefore, we do not need to use induction on $n$. Is that right?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, Can you tell me your comments about the above solution?

Comment: can you please find a formula for $$g''(x)$$?